# Rule runs out of order and it finishes after the hook finishes

Tags: javascript, auth0, rules

I am encountering a very strange problem.
I have 4 rules in my Auth flow.

1. Add user metadata from idp -> Adds some fields on the user_metadata from the identity provider
2. the rule that has the problem: It saves the user to my DB and adds to user_metadata the ID field which is from the created user, and console logs
   3)add role
   4)enrich access token and console logs

So my problem would be that rule 4) needs the ID from rule 2) but rule2 code (or part of it) runs just after the hook finishes
If i log the output with the real time logs extension it's like the following:

1. new webtask request
2. console.log from rule 4
3. finished webtask request
4. console.log from rule 2

I'll attach my code for the rule2 so you can see what's happening

the code for rule 2 is:

```
function (user, context, callback) {
    //removed for simplicity
  const { user_metadata: { firstName, lastName, email } } = user;
  user.user_metadata = user.user_metadata || {};

  // create user 
  const createUser = async (user) => {
    const url = `${apiUrl}/admin/users`;
    const body = { firstName, lastName, email };
    const options = { headers: { 'Authorization': `Api-Key ${apiKey}` } };
    const { data: { data } } = await axios
      .post(url, body, options);

    user.user_metadata.id = data.id;
    return user;
  };

  const addIdToUserMetadata = (async () => {
    const createdUser = await createUser(user);
    console.log('createdUser', createdUser);
        await auth0.users.updateUserMetadata(user.user_id, user.user_metadata);
    })();

  return callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Comment: You're not awaiting the IIFE that calls `updateUserMetadata()`

Comment: @Barmar how can i await the IIFE? I'm already awaiting the `.updateUserMetadata` method

Comment: Don't use an IIFE. Just put the code in your function. But you have to make the function async in order to use `await`.

Comment: @Barmar i understand, okay, so i'll remove the IIFE but then how can i call that function? I would need to call it hence me needing to create another IIFE

Comment: When you're using async operations, you either have to define async functions so you can `await`, or use explicit promises, or use explicit callbacks. You can't magically turn async code into synchronous.

Comment: Put the call to `callback()` inside the IIFE. But you can't return its value, since it runs asynchronously.

Comment: Ah nevermind, what I did is i made the main function async, removed the IIFE pattern and just await called addIdToUserMetadata